# managing 1000+connection using boost in client

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, tcpclient, tcplistener

Here I am working Gateway simulator purpose of the gateway is to connect with data center and stream video to data center if data center request it.

Here gateway simulator can simulate 1000 gateway.that means each gateway will connect with data center.Here i am confused how to manage this much of socket in the gateway.

In c++ select can be used for this purpose do demultiplex the connection with data center.since here I may have to to create 1000 connect select is not appropriate .

I figured out managing multiple  client in server by taking acceptor.async  method and handler will take of that.

But since gateway is client application

how can manage multiple connection so that I can get request from data center for each connection.

Gateway will run on both windows an linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were my problem to solve, I'd try first with [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/). Libevent automatically picks the 'best available' mechanism for each platform, whether that is `epoll`, or `kqueue`, or `select`, and allows you to focus on what is unique to your program.

Comment: @chris_vr, guess again :) "Libevent should compile on Linux, *BSD, Mac OS X, Solaris and Windows." Admittedly the last changelog entry that mentions windows specifically is a little old, but it is advertised to work.

Comment: Yeah Correct libevent works on windows as well.Can't we implement epoll using boost.the problem I am  unaware about libevent lib.

Answer (score 3):

- Windows: `WSAEventSelect`
- Linux: `epoll`
- FreeBSD: `kqueue`

Comment: plz. Tell me the steps using boost.How can I demultiplex 1000 connection if client 100 connection with the same server(data center).

Comment: It seems for both linux and windows I need to take different strategy for this situation.Am I correct?

Comment: @Chris_vr: Neither Linux nor Windows have any problem handling 1000 connections if you use the more efficient ways of managing the sockets. I don't know what socket notification mechanism boost::asio uses - but the three mechanisms I mentioned should not have any problems handling 1000 connections if used properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Boost.Asio - this might be possible, but I'd have to do research into it. 
Boost.Asio doesn't appear to have any implementation that calls WSAWaitForMultipleEvents, so I don't know that there's existing support for what you need.

In Windows at the very least WSAWaitForMultipleEvents is your answer. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742219(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It seems for both linux and windows I need to take different strategy for this situation.Am I correct?

Comment: Overlapped IO is most definitely the best way to go performance-wise, but you could use WSAWaitForMultipleEvents - you could dispatch a number of worker threads to handle the active connections.